# Não consigo colocar simbolo hamburguer no Navigation Drawer Panel

Tags: java, android

Estou a tentar colocar um `navigation Drawer Panel` na minha app, mas não consigo colocar o simbolo hamburguer na minha `MainActivity`.
O codigo que estou a usar é:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

O aspeto é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

XML do toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/brown"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/app_name2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

toolbar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/amarelo1" android:endColor="@color/amarelo2"  />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Já tentei colocar `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);` e também não funciona. Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou inserir o `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`

Comment: @acklay tentei agora e continua sem aparecer.

Comment: @ramaral ja tinha tentado, mas continuo sem conseguir. Coloquei um pequeno printscreen do que me aparece. A unica solução que me lembro é colocar um ImageButton na Toolbar, mas não deveria ser necessário.

Comment: Coloque o XML do seu Toolbar na sua pergunta.

Comment: @acklay atualizei.

Comment: Abaixo de `Toolbar toolbar...`, coloque `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`;

Comment: @acklay ja coloquei. Ficou igual.

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado.

Comment: Você compilou e nada?! Nesse XML que você colocou aqui, eu não estou vendo nenhum DrawerLayout . Porque?

Comment: @acklay porque o DrawerLayout está noutro xml, o activity_main.xml onde eu tenho um include e chamo o XML do toolbar q coloquei aqui. 
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: Aqui comigo aparece o botão normalmente usando seu código. Dê uma olhada nesse meu projeto aqui e veja se tem allguma coisa que não tem no seu https://github.com/cleidimarviana/navDrawer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/seamusdawkins/MainActivity.java

Comment: @acklay obrigada, vou ver.

Answer (score 0):

Mantenha a instância do `DrawerToggle` e chame o `syncState()` em `onPostCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.drawerToggle.syncState();
}
```